# почему парится только один запрос?

Tags: python-3.x, requests, bs4, lxml

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

URL = 'https://miped.ru/'
HEDERS = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
}
req = requests.get(URL, headers=HEDERS)

src = req.text

# with open('index.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
#     file.write(src)

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

all_content = {}
all_content1 = []
content = soup.find_all('div', class_="news-items")

#------------------------ВОТ ТУТ------------------------------------------
for item in content:
    name = item.find('a', class_="news-item-header__title").next.text
    link = item.find('a', class_="news-item-header__title").get('href')
    all_content[name] = link
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
with open('pars_EpicG.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(all_content, file , indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

При парсинге сайта https://miped.ru/ задачей было просто вытащить название статьи и ссылку но почему то вытаскивает только одно  название и одну ссылку соответственно первую

Comment: Проблема выше, Вы ищите все теги с классом `news-items`, но он один. Поэтому `find_all` вернет список с единственным первым элементом.

Comment: у меня не один [https://sun9-72.userapi.com/impg/OZ8e0bubGBVdj-trneUkZKYvmuJNeHpu2sJKNA/VwSkZWeFTeI.jpg?size=1280x720&quality=96&sign=b1cb0fe5f317007206fb8097267339b2&type=album] или я чего-то не понял ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы перепутали `class` блока `div`.
Вы указали `news-items`, а нужно `news-item`.